Definition of the Bayes Optimal Predictor with a conditional probability
I am reading the book "Understanding Machine Learning" by Shalev-Shwartz and Ben-David and I have a problem about how a certain conditional probability is define.
Here is the context :

For a probability distribution, $D$, over $ \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} $, one can measure how likely $h$ is to make an error when labeled points are randomly drawn according to $D$. We redefine the true error (or risk) of a prediction rule $h$ to be
$$
L_{\mathcal{D}}(h) \overset{\text{def}}{=} \mathbb{P}_{(x,y) \sim \mathcal{D}}[h(x) \neq y] \overset{\text{def}}{=} \mathcal{D}(\{(x,y) : h(x) \neq y\}). \tag{3.1}
$$

Here $\mathcal{Y} = \{0,1\}$ and $ \mathcal{X}$ can be $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mathbb{N}$, or a finite set, as far as I have seen in the book.
Then the "Bayes Optimal Predictor" is defined as such:

Given any probability distribution $D$ over $\mathcal{X} \times \{0,1\}$, the best label predicting function from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\{0,1\}$ will be
$$
f_D(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } \mathbb{P}[y = 1 | x] \geq 1/2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to verify [...] that for every probability distribution $D$, the Bayes optimal predictor $f_D$ is optimal, in the sense that no other classifier, $g : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ has a lower error. That is, for every classifier $g$, $L_D(f_D) \leq L_D(g)$.

In order to verify this statement I need to understand what is exactly $\mathbb{P}[y = 1 | x]$ ; of course if $ \mathcal{X}$ would happen to be discrete, when $\mathbb{P}[ x] > 0$ (where $\mathbb{P}$ would be the marginal of $D$ over $\mathcal{X}$), then there is no problem in defining  $\mathbb{P}[y = 1 | x]$. Or, also if $D_{|\mathcal{X}}$ would have a density over $\mathcal{X} =\mathbb{R}^d$, but in the general case, I fail to see how to define this quantity.
